# Use all units in campaign

Tags: starcraft-2

So in the campaign you go along and slowly get new units and buildings and it progresses (for both WOL and HOTS). I am wondering if there is a way to disable this and build any unit or building despite the mission?

I would care if say wraiths couldn't be built since they are a campaign only unit. But I think it would be cool to replay it trying some different strategies. Ya, it'd be unfair, but oh well, it would be fun.

I'm looking for campaign centered answers. I love the SC2 multi player and the campaign is great and I want to find a new way to experience it.

Anyways, any help appreciated.

Comment: There is not, for Wings of Liberty. Heart of the Swarm *kinda* has what you're asking, where the master archives allow you to replay any mission with the maximum possible kerrigan level + your choice of evolution / mutations.

Comment: Well that sucks @RavenDreamer but, what are you going to do. The Kerrigan thing is cool, I may try that. Have a Leviathan swoop down every once an a while lol!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you could possibly do is create a custom campaign using the map files from Wings of Liberty/ Heart of the Swarm, and tweak them to give yourself the units that you want.

- Open up the SC2 Map Editor, and select the 'Open Folder' menu
- Click on the campaign tab. A warning should appear about spoilers. Accept it.
- You should see a list of files. These are the actual in-game mission files. The Heart of the Swarm maps should be in a folder called `swarm`.
- Open the maps, and save a copy of all of them (in case you stuff up and need to revert back.)

Once you're done, you could access the maps from your custom campaign directory in game.

Here's a more in depth explanation of [how to find the campaign mission files](http://au.ign.com/wikis/starcraft-2/Campaign_Maps/Mods_%28Wings_of_Liberty%29)

Comment: SOLID! Can't wait to try this out.